# Draw a pattern using for loops in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

Can you guys please help me out here?
I have to print that **kind** of pattern [Example for pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZtNyB.png)

in that example the input for the size is 21.

```
for (int row = 0; row < size; row++)
    for (int col = 0; col < size; col++) {
        if (row == 0 && col == 0 || row == 0 && col == size - 1 || row == size - 1 && col == 0 || row == size - 1 && col == size - 1)
            printf("+");
        if ((row == 0 || row == size - 1) && (col > 0 && col < size - 1))
            printf("-");
        if ((row > 0 && row < size - 1) && (col == 0 || col == size - 1))
            printf("|");
        if ((row > 0 && row < size - 1) && (col > 0 && col < size - 1)) {
            if (row == col)
                printf("\\");
            else
            if (col == size - 2)
                printf("/");
            else
            if (row == x && col == x)
                printf("X");
            else
                printf(" ");
        }
    }
```

This is the code i wrote but it is not good .
How can I fix it ?
Thank you!

Comment: Please explain/show why the code is "not good". Is the output not that what you expect, is the code hard to read...

Comment: @StephanLechner the output was wrong and now I also get an error when I try to run it for some reason.. I didn't get errors before..

Comment: "It's not good", "The output was wrong", "I get an error", "for some reason" -- please try to be specific when you describe what you expect and what you get.. By the way, you don't seem to print any newlines after each line.

Comment: @MOehm sorry my bad I tried to attach a pic along my comment

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You missed couple of things, read the comments in the code below to check what I corrected.

Here is the working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    int size = 21;
    int x = size / 2;    // You want x in the middle so its size / 2;
    int i = 1;

    for (int row = 0; row < size; row++, i++)    // Incrementing 'i' too
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < size; col++)
        {
            // In this first if statement below you should put parenthesis around && conditions for better readability and to get rid of any warnings compiler might put out
            if ((row == 0 && col == 0) || (row == 0 && col == size - 1) || (row == size - 1 && col == 0) || (row == size - 1 && col == size - 1))
                printf("+");
            if ((row == 0 || row == size - 1) && (col > 0 && col < size - 1))
                printf("-");
            if ((row > 0 && row < size - 1) && (col == 0 || col == size - 1))
                printf("|");
            if ((row > 0 && row < size - 1) && (col > 0 && col < size - 1))
            {
                if (row == x && col == x)    // This should be your first check because in case you are in the middle you want to put 'x' and don't care about rest of the if-else statement
                    printf("X");
                else if (row == col)
                    printf("\\");
                else if (col == size - i)    // Instead size - 2, you put here size - i, which is initialized to 1 and incremented by 1 in the outer for loop
                    printf("/");
                else
                    printf(" ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");    // You want to print out the new line at the end of every row
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is another solution ,

```
int main()
{
    int size =5;
    int counter = 0;

    printf("+");
    for(int k=1;k<=size+1;k++){
        printf("-");

    }

    printf("+");
    printf("\n");
    }
    for(int i=1;i<=size;i++){
        printf("|");
        for(int j=1;j<=size;j++){
            if(j==0 || j==i )
                printf("\\");
            else
                printf(" ");

            if(counter==0){
                if(j==size){
                    printf("/");
                    counter++;                  
                }
            }
            else if(j==size-i+1)
                printf("/");

            if(j==size)
                printf("|");    

        }
        printf("\n");

    }   
    printf("+");
    for(int k=1;k<=size+1;k++){
        printf("-");

    }
    printf("+");
    printf("\n");

    return 0;

}
```